# Cannot get to Upgrade Now screen - Upgrade from 4.4.3 to 4.5.1 - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, upgrade, 4.5

I am trying to upgrade CiviCRM from 4.4.3 to 4.5.1 (and eventually go to the latest version. I am doing it incrementally 4.4-4.5-4.6-4.7 to be safe). I have been following these steps

https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC45/Upgrade+WordPress+Sites+to+4.6

I am stuck at step 4:

- Point your web browser to the following URL (you should already be logged in to Wordpress with administrator-level permissions):
  http://wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/upgrade&reset=1

I copied the civicrm.settings.php file to the civicrm folder after I uploaded the new 4.5.1 files. When I try to go to the link above I get a Page Not Found error

If I remove the civicrm.settings.php file I get a Page Isn't working error

Does anyone have any idea on what I need to do here? Thank you so much for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kevin is right, there's no need to stop at each intermediate release--you can just download the latest and upgrade all the way through.

In fact, even besides wasted time, it's generally a bad idea to upgrade through in-between releases. The point releases fix bugs, and sometimes the bug they fix is a bad upgrader.

On occasion, an upgrade from a *really* old version (you'd be surprised at some of the Civi911 calls) will fail if we try it straight through, while it works if it's broken into a couple of pieces.  Still, the process would be to upgrade to the *last* of the 4.5 series (for example) and then to the latest version.  You should generally never upgrade to the .0 or .1 unless that's the latest release.

Answer (score 1):

When I last did this, I went to  4.4.latest and then jumped to 4.6.15

I was able to bypass the 4.5 upgrade, the 4.6.x upgrade has all the db update scripts so you will not miss anything.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my CiviCRM upgrade problem. The documentation said to enter xxxxxxx/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/… I looked further into that location and found the actual path on the server to admin.php was /home/xxxxxx/public_html/wordpress/wp-admin The path actually had to be xxxxxxx/wordpress/wp-admim/admin.php?... Once I put that into the browser it brought me to the upgrade page. I am working on the upgrade now. I did upgrade straight to the newest version.Thanks for working with me on this